# Unattended Installation Ubuntu through bootable pendrive

Tags: 16.04, server, system-installation, preseed, kickstart

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 through unattended installation.
It has been installed successfully, but after installation, it is not loading and a black screen is showing with only the message:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 57837/30523392 files, 2295190/122072832 blocks
```

Comment: With this error, how can you claim "installed successfully"?